# Creating a Swift Framework with OpenCV as a 3rd party framework, but not packaging OpenCV in the end framework

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks

Im currently working on creating a Swift Framework, my framework currently includes OpenCV as a Linked Framework. I have read up on the standards for distributing frameworks, and many people say that frameworks shouldn't be compiled/packaged with other 3rd party frameworks as this can cause issues like framework collisions etc...

So I knowing this I have been trying to work out how to build my framework but without packaging OpenCV with it, so the application will have to depend on OpenCV in order to use my framework.

I've had a look into Cocoa Pods and how the dependency management there will handle this for me. The problem with Cocoa Pods is the distribution, we need to be able to carefully control who can gain access to the framework.

So in conclusion, what would be the best way to create my framework without including the 3rd party dependency? Im open to any ideas!

This is the first framework I've created and some help or pointers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Jake Wade, have you found any solution for this? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @TuanDo Sorry mate didn't find a fix for it, we just bundled it in with the end framework not ideal but we couldn't get it to work. Will let you know if I find something in the future

Comment: Thank you mate for letting me know but how did you bundle it with the framework, did you use OpenCV source code or the open CV framework itself?

Comment: We used the openCV Framework and that seemed to work fine, you could maybe try building the openCV framework using CMake as a dynamic lib / dylib that could work, but we've never tried it

Comment: Thank you @Jake Wade, I used open CV Framework and embedded inside the framework. It works well.

Comment: No worries! Keep in mind this may cause clashes if the implementor of your framework also uses OpenCV.